# Rcpp Beginner Error Message

Tags: rcpp

I'm beginner to Rcpp I had this error message to run the following R code. I use Windows 10. 
"Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warning message:"

```
incltxt <- '
int fibonacci(const int x) {
if (x == 0) return(0);
if (x == 1) return(1);
return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}'


fibRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="int"),
plugin="Rcpp",
incl=incltxt,
body='
int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);
return Rcpp::wrap( fibonacci(x) );
')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the simpler and newer `cppFunction()`:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction('int f(int n) { if (n < 2) return n; return f(n-1) + f(n-2);}')
R> f(10)
[1] 55
R>
```

*Edit:* And here is your repaired code. You need to also load Rcpp to have its plugin registered:

```
R> library(Rcpp)                                                                                        
R> library(inline)                                                                                      
R> incltxt <- '                                                                                         
+ int fibonacci(const int x) {                                                                          
+ if (x == 0) return(0);                                                                                
+ if (x == 1) return(1);                                                                                
+ return fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2);                                                           
+ }'                                                                                                    
R> bodytxt <- '                                                                                         
+ int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);                                                                            
+ return Rcpp::wrap( fibonacci(x) );                                                                    
+ '                                                                                                     
R> fibRcpp <- inline::cxxfunction(signature(xs="int"), incl=incltxt, body=bodytxt, plugin="Rcpp")       
R> fibRcpp(10)
R> 55
```

Comment: It works great for cppFunction but if I want to use incltxt how can I code with cppFunction?

Comment: Why do you insist on cppFunction? It is from the inline package; what we have now is better.

Comment: My main problem is to make my Gibbs sampling code faster as it is used too many times in my project and it takes around 1 day to finish running. I thought solution might be write my R Gibbs sampling code as text in C++ like incltxt.

Comment: No, write the same code _more easily using Rcpp Attributes_. You get the same speed.  Read the vignette 'Rcpp Attributes'.